# JSF 2 : Is it possible to inherit @ManagedBean?

Tags: java, jsf, inheritance

I have a `Bean` ,with a [@ManagedBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html) annotation, defined like this :

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

Now, I have another bean defined like this :

```
public class FooBean extends Bean {
    // properties, methods here ...
}
```

When I try to reference FooBean in my JSF page, I have the following error :
`Target Unreachable, identifier 'fooBean' resolved to null`

Why JSF doesn't see `FooBean` as a managed bean ?

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6661499/363573

Answer (score 9):

The point Alex is trying to make is that you're confusing classes with instances. This is a classic (pun intended) OOP mistake.

The @ManagedBean annotation does not work on classes per-se. It works on **instances** of such classes, defining an instance that is managed.

If your bean is defined like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

Then it means you have a session-scoped **instance**, called myBean (or whatever you want to name it).

Therefore, all classes that are subclasses of the MyBean **class** are not managed by default. Furthermore, how does JSF recognize where you're using the subclasses? If so, what names are you giving to those instances? (Because you have to give them some name, otherwise, how would JSF manage them?)

So, let's say you have another class:

```
Class MyOtherClass {
    private MyBean myBeanObject; // myBeanObject isn't managed. 
}
```

what happens to the @PostConstruct and all the other annotations you used? Nothing. If you created the instance of MyBean, then it's YOU who manages it, not JavaServerFaces. So it's not really a managed bean, just a common object that you use.

However, things change completely when you do this:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
Class MyOtherClassBean {
    @ManagedProperty("#{myBean}")
    private MyBean myBeanObject;

    public void setMyBeanObject(...) { ... }
    public MyBeanClass getMyBeanObject() { ... }
}
```

Then again, what is managed is not the class, but the **instance** of the class. Having a ManagedBean means that you only have one instance of that bean (per scope, that is).

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation. However, why does http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html have the @Inherited annotation ?

Comment: @Stephan good question. Maybe it was an idea that was later abandoned when implementing the ManagedBean behavior.

Answer (score 5):

do you need `BaseBean` to be a managed bean? Since you name it `BaseBean`, I assume that this bean hold commonality between all your other managed bean. If so then it should not contain `@ManagedBean` annotation. Do this

```
public abstract BaseBean{
    //...
}
```

Then inside your managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class FooBean extends BaseBean{
    //...
}
```

Comment: By doing this, I'll have to put @ManagedBean on all my beans ... this is what I want to avoid !

Comment: @Stephan: Why do you avoid putting annotation on all your managed bean? I do not know what you put inside your `BaseBean`, but from the way you name it, it should be set of commonality between all managed bean, so you should not annotated it @ManagedBean since it is not really a controller/gateway to your `Model`. You have your `BaseBean` to be `SessionScoped`, so every bean inherit from `BaseBean` will be SessionScoped whether you want it or not. You do not want to keep too many things in Session. What if you want to create a managed bean that has RequestScoped and inherit `BaseBean`.

Comment: To be more clearly : Is it possible to inherit @ManagedBean ?